# What is the last macbook or macbook pro model that had a replaceable battery and hdd?

Tags: macbook-pro

I was thinking of buying a used macbook or macbook pro and plan to replace the battery and HDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can replace the battery and HDD/SSD on most MacBook Pro models. Have a look at the manuals on [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro).

[MacBook Pro 13" Retina Display Mid 2014](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_13%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2014):

- You can replace the battery like [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+Battery+Replacement/27832)
- And the SSD like [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27849).

[MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2012](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_13%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2014):

- I think the last HDD MacBook Pro. No retina display, but you can replace the optical drive and use a 2nd HDD/SSD instead.

Answer (score 0):

Current-production MBP and MBA (Air) laptops have replaceable batteries and storage.

If you really mean "user-replaceable" then we have to go back to the  MacBook (no pro) models of 2008. It's pretty easy to identify - flip it over, if there is a very obvious latch (aluminum) or coin-slot release (plastic) then you can change the battery in 30 seconds with no tools and the drive in 5 minutes with a common screwdriver.

Newer models have the battery completely inside the case. You will need 2-3 different types of screwdrivers, some rather specific (but quite cheap) electronics tools and about 30 minutes to swap out the battery and/or storage. Longer if that model has the battery glued to the case.

The 2015 Macbook (the super-thin one) does not have user-replaceable anything. The battery is glued to the case, and the storage is soldered to the logic card (it's too small to be called a "board") so you are stuck with whatever you ordered. But unlikely it will need anything for 5+ years.